# dlopen fails with file not found when file is in correct path

Tags: libtool, dlopen

I have a library built using libtool which is install into the package's library directory, `/usr/local/lib/myprog/libmylib.so`. I'm dynamically loading the library in my code with libltdl. When I try to load this library on one machine, it works just fine. On another, with the same build and the library installed on the same location, I get a "file not found" error.

If I call `lt_dlforeachfile` directly before `lt_dlopenext` (which I use to load the library), then I can see by printing out filenames that the library I need has been found in the search path. But then immediately after, loading it fails with a "file not found" error. Any suggestions?

**UPDATE**

I have tried switching to using `dlopen` and explicitly specifying the absolute path to the library. This still works on some systems and not on the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out that libltdl was hiding the real error. the "file not found" was from another library that the library I was loading depended on. I discovered this when using `dlerror()` to print the error messages. After installing the missing library, all is well!

Comment: Another way to debug that kind of error is given [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9567335/1043187).