# How to get more info if lt_dlopen fails?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, libtool

I'm calling `lt_dlopen` and getting a generic file not found error (translated errno text). How can I get more information about what is actually failing, as the file is definitely there.

This is a C++ program loading a C++ library. Otherwhere in the same program I use the same command to open other libraries without a problem, thus I fear it might be something specific to this library.  I've used `ldd` and all those dependencies of the library are met.

Comment: You could `strace` your program...

Comment: `strace` doesn't show anything that might indicate a problem.

Comment: You could also use `ltrace`. Are you sure that `lt_dlopen` is passed the full absolute path of a `*.so`file? Check with `file` about it..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I stumbled across something that kind of works:

```
export LD_DEBUG=all
```

And then proceed to sift throught the extreme mass of output. In this case I found a "lookup error" and one of the symbols could not be resolved.  I'm not sure why, but that is perhaps not relevant to this question.

Comment: Just as a tip for anyone else, I got this same generic file not found error because of using `lt_dlopen` in a multi thread context, which is illegal https://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/html_node/Thread-Safety-in-libltdl.html#Thread-Safety-in-libltdl

Answer (score 0):

Recompile libtool with "-DLT_DEBUG_LOADERS" in $CFLAGS. Adjust LD_LIBRARY_PATH so that your program will find this debug libltdl.so instead of the system one. That debug version of ltdl will print explicit errors for each loader's attempt to open the target with much less verbosity than LD_DEBUG=all.

Answer (score -1):

From http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/libtool/libtool_46.html :

> `Function: lt_dlhandle lt_dlopen (const char *filename)`
>
> [...] If lt_dlopen fails for any reason, it returns NULL.
>
> `Function: const char * lt_dlerror (void)`
>
> Return a human readable string describing the most recent error that
>   occurred from any of libltdl's functions. Return NULL if no errors
>   have occurred since initialization or since it was last called.

Comment: That message is also just "file not found"

Comment: Well, I was hoping something more could come out of this, but since the information you provide is sparse, I could only guess. It didn't work...